# Debug datetime formatting in django

Tags: django

I've inherited a django project, and there's a model with a datetime field (yes, the model is called "Test", as in "lab test")

```
class Test(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateTimeField()
```

This field is formatted as `May 16, 2017, 9:55 a.m.` in the template, and I need to change that, but have no idea where this formatting is coming from, and hence how to change it.

Here's the template code, the able is built in a for loop, nothing fancy, and then modified with datatables.net JavaScript (which I can disable and has no effect, so formatting is applied before that):

```
{% load static i18n tz epoch_tag postman_tags %}
...
{% for test in tests %}
    ...
    <td>{{ test.datetime|default_if_none:"" }}</td>
    ...
{% endfor %}
...
```

The view is a standard `ListView` with a normal queryset, nothing odd there.

Here's what I have in the settings, after un-commenting various lines:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
# Doesn't work
DATE_FORMAT = "Y-m-d"
SHORT_DATETIME_FORMAT = "Y-m-d"
#USE_I18N = True
#USE_L10N = True
#USE_TZ = True
```

Here are the context processors, with the ones I've tried commenting out:

```
'django.template.context_processors.request',
#'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
'apps.postman.context_processors.inbox',
'apps.biomarker.context_processors.base_template_for_user_type',
'apps.menus.context_processors.menu_elements',
#'django.template.context_processors.tz',
'django_settings_export.settings_export',
'apps.biomarker.context_processors.custom_pages',
'apps.hm_multitenancy.context_processors.add_practice_context'
```

The third party apps, with the ones I've tried commenting out:

```
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
#'django.contrib.humanize',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.sitemaps',

'django_tables2',
'django_countries',
#'easytz',
'allauth',
'allauth.account',
'rest_framework',
'django_filters',
'django_inlinecss',
'django_extensions',
'crispy_forms',
'rosetta',
'ckeditor',
'ckeditor_uploader',
'impersonate',
'corsheaders',
'email_log',
```

- I've removed any JavaScript that may be interfering.
- I've tried changing the field to a property that returns a string to see if it might cause an exception in case I got lucky but no avail.
- There in nothing in the model that I can see interfering.
- There is a dir locale/en/LC_MESSAGES but I don't know if there's anything in there that might affect it.

Any help on figuring this out would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to format those dates according to your needs might be using the `date` filter, since you say the date is being inserted by the template engine. It is extensively documented here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date

Just do the following (as the documentation example shows):

```
{{test.datetime|date:"D d M Y"}}
```

Comment: I'm accepting this, and suspect the format I'm seeing is perhaps a default in the absence of a filter. Thanks.